# Do anonymous methods consume memory?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

Do [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx), [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and alike, allocate/consume/eat memory on your computer?

If so, do they allocate same memory on each variable on captured code block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course they do, just like any other normal function. How can they be executed at run time if they wouldn't be "stored" somewhere in memory?

But if you are asking if they consume more memory on every call (as in allocating dynamic memory), then no, they don't do that on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Every single thing will need some kind of backing store in memory, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a delegates defines a new class. So this needs memory to store information about the class (also at runtime).

Defining a `Func` or `Action` with specific generic types defines (hidden from you) a new class at runtime. So this also needs memory.

Anonymous methods are made into a normal method with a gibberish name by the compiler, and put in a private class. Then, just like any other method, it will require memory at runtime to store the code that must be executed. And the class will require some memory just like other classes.